# Debugging cocos 2d-x android project with ndk

Tags: android, eclipse, android-ndk, cocos2d-x

I am trying to debug a cocos 2d-x android project in eclipse using android ndk but i am getting following error

**NDK: Please run build/tools/gen-platforms.sh to build the corresponding directory**

My Console Output is as following

```
    [2014-04-21 16:12:28 - Check4] Unknown Application ABI: 
[2014-04-21 16:12:28 - Check4] Android
[2014-04-21 16:12:28 - Check4] Unknown Application ABI: 
[2014-04-21 16:12:28 - Check4] NDK:
[2014-04-21 16:12:28 - Check4] Unknown Application ABI: 
[2014-04-21 16:12:28 - Check4] Could
[2014-04-21 16:12:28 - Check4] Unknown Application ABI: 
[2014-04-21 16:12:28 - Check4] not
[2014-04-21 16:12:28 - Check4] Unknown Application ABI: 
[2014-04-21 16:12:28 - Check4] find
[2014-04-21 16:12:28 - Check4] Unknown Application ABI: 
[2014-04-21 16:12:28 - Check4] platform
[2014-04-21 16:12:28 - Check4] Unknown Application ABI: 
[2014-04-21 16:12:28 - Check4] files
[2014-04-21 16:12:28 - Check4] Unknown Application ABI: 
[2014-04-21 16:12:28 - Check4] (headers
[2014-04-21 16:12:28 - Check4] Unknown Application ABI: 
[2014-04-21 16:12:28 - Check4] and
[2014-04-21 16:12:28 - Check4] Unknown Application ABI: 
[2014-04-21 16:12:28 - Check4] libraries)
[2014-04-21 16:12:28 - Check4] Unknown Application ABI: 
[2014-04-21 16:12:28 - Check4] 
[2014-04-21 16:12:28 - Check4] Unknown Application ABI: 
[2014-04-21 16:12:28 - Check4] 
[2014-04-21 16:12:28 - Check4] Unknown Application ABI: 
[2014-04-21 16:12:28 - Check4] 
[2014-04-21 16:12:28 - Check4] Unknown Application ABI: 
[2014-04-21 16:12:28 - Check4] 
Android
[2014-04-21 16:12:28 - Check4] Unknown Application ABI: 
[2014-04-21 16:12:28 - Check4] NDK:
[2014-04-21 16:12:28 - Check4] Unknown Application ABI: 
[2014-04-21 16:12:28 - Check4] Please
[2014-04-21 16:12:28 - Check4] Unknown Application ABI: 
[2014-04-21 16:12:28 - Check4] run
[2014-04-21 16:12:28 - Check4] Unknown Application ABI: 
[2014-04-21 16:12:28 - Check4] build/tools/gen-platforms.sh
[2014-04-21 16:12:28 - Check4] Unknown Application ABI: 
[2014-04-21 16:12:28 - Check4] to
[2014-04-21 16:12:28 - Check4] Unknown Application ABI: 
[2014-04-21 16:12:28 - Check4] build
[2014-04-21 16:12:28 - Check4] Unknown Application ABI: 
[2014-04-21 16:12:28 - Check4] the
[2014-04-21 16:12:28 - Check4] Unknown Application ABI: 
[2014-04-21 16:12:28 - Check4] corresponding
[2014-04-21 16:12:28 - Check4] Unknown Application ABI: 
[2014-04-21 16:12:28 - Check4] directory.
[2014-04-21 16:12:28 - Check4] Unable to detect application ABI's
```

NDK version -android-ndk-r9c..
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Against which platform API level are you compiling against ?
Try setting the same level for the minSdkVersion inside your manifest and the Application.mk file, and check you have the headers for this platform (inside `ndk/platforms/`)

Example:

- AndroidManifest.xml : `android:minSdkVersion="14"`
- jni/**Application**.mk : `APP_PLATFORM := android-14`